# SQLite3 version 3.34 - the callback function

Tags: c#, c++, c, sqlite, dllimport

I am using C# to run the sqlite3_exec API available in [SQLite3.DLL](https://sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3340000.zip). (care! this link will download)

I import the API as follows:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3.dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_exec", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int sqlite3_exec(IntPtr dbHandle, string sql, Callback callback, object args, out IntPtr errmsg);
```

The API signature is [found here](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)

I've defined a delegate for the 3rd parameter, the callback as follows:

```
public delegate int Callback(IntPtr p, int n, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]string[] names, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]string[] values);
```

Something is amiss (and I can't see what that is) because I hit this error *consistently* after retrieving the 3rd record i.e. during the 4th callback

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I'd appreciate your help in resolving the issue or for any pointers leading thereto.

Comment: I'd suggest not doing that (The callback interface is rarely the best way to do something even in C), and sticking with the normal sqlite3 C# bindings and its API.

Comment: This cannot be debugged without an [mcve].